# Rows into Columns using Dynamic SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

I am using MySQL Server Management Studio and have 3 tables, Person, ClientDiagnosis and Diagnosis. These tables have rows with data that I want to appear as columns. I have found similar questions here and one answer that seemed to come close: a suggestion to use dynamic sql because the number of columns will vary based on the rows.

This is what I have (forgive the formatting as I didn't see a markdown for tables. I'd be happy to fix it if someone can tell me how):

---

### PERSONID |AXIS_NUM|DIAGNOSIS_NAME

### 1        |         1       |Depression

### 1        |         1       |Eating Disorder

### 2        |         1       | Psychosis

### 3        |         2       | Eating Disorder

### 1        |         1       | Psychosis

### 2        |         1       |Medically Induced Psychosis

And I'd like it to look like this:

### PERSONID |AXIS_NUM 1 (I)| AXIS_NUM 1 (II)|AXIS_NUM 1 (III)|AXIS_NUM 2 (I)|

### 1 |Depression|Eating Disorder|Psychosis|Null

### 2 | Psychosis |Medically Induced Psychosis|Null|Null

### 3|Null|Null|Null|| Eating Disorder

This is the code I'm working with:

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'max(CASE WHEN AxisNum = ''',
      AxisNum,
      ''' THEN d.DiagnosisID END) AS `',
      AxisNum, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM ClientDiagnosis;


SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT p.personid ', @sql, ' 
           from Person p
           left join ClientDiagnosis cd
             on p.Personid = cd.pdid
           left join Diagnosis d
             on cd.DiagnosisID=d.diagnosisid
           group by p.Personid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I am so new to dynamic sql that I can't debug this so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to "pivot".  I have a Stored Procedure that will do much of the work for you.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I wondered if there might be another way. I will try this.